# Keep previous SAP and private domains

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package

I have one use case where is necessary to migrate one client from stack S7 to stack S50. I know that is not possible to copy SAPs and private domains between accounts of different stacks but is it possible to buy a new SAP and new private domain and use the subdomains of the old account keeping the subdomains that clients already are familiar with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use same subdomains on both stacks - even if you purchase additional SAP and PDs. The DNS settings for both are stack specific, so they will conflict if you try to apply it on two stacks simultaneously. And there will be an issue with DNS breaking once the domains are moved to the new stack as any content (unsubs, images, etc.) sent from the old account would stop working.

As you, regardless, can't take your IP with you from S7 to S50, you are faced with an IP warmup - which as well can be done using new domains, both for SAP and PD.

My recommendation will be to purchase new SAPs and PDs, use new subdomains, and go for an IP warmup. As you want to do the cutover as swift as possible, you can approach it somewhat differently. Instead of initiating the account with a single IP, and slowly ramping up the volume, you can start with e.g. 10 IP adresses and remove them one by one, let's say once per week. This will have the same result, as your volume/IP will increase similarly to the classic approach. And this will allow you to start sending with full volume from S50 on day 1 of your operations.

You will need to purchase all the additional IP addresses from Salesforce, but the period you need them for is limited to the duration of your warmup.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas but as the old account will be discomissed, we could change DNS entries in the old domains and point to the new stack no? Is there any issue doing this?

Comment: @PedroLopes the issue is, the moment you switch the DNS, the links and images in the emails you have sent will immediately stop working - as they will point to the wrong instance where urls don’t resolve correctly

Comment: You are right @LukasLunow, indeed that will impact due the SAP. So a mix situation between setting up a new subdomain for a new SAP and change the DNS entry only for the domain used as private domain due the fact it is only user for Sender identification “From Address”. Do you see any issue with this setup?

Comment: Yes, @PedroLopes - new SAP subdomain and a switch of PD to S50 will do the trick. And again, be cautious around IP warmup.

Comment: Thanks @LukasLunow

Comment: You’re welcome @PedroLopes